# Having issues with AM/PM with DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I have some code that I want to test for a valid time and for some reason it works for dates with PM's but not AM.

So I'm taking in formats that correspond to this format:

6/1/2018 12:00:00 PM

However for some reason or another this is working great when it's PM but when I replace it with AM it breaks. The format in acceptableformats I'm accepting it to hit is:

M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt

The below fails saying that it's false:

```
      DateTimeOffset dateTimeResult;
        var acceptableFormats = new string[] {
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK",
                            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.FFFK",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssK",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            "yyyyMMdd",
                            "MM/dd/yyyy",
                            "M/d/yyyy",
                            "yyyy-MM",
                            "yyyy" };
        DateTimeOffset dateTimeResult;
        var timeOffset = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact("6/1/2018 12:00:00 AM", acceptableFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTimeResult);
```

This works says it's true:

```
      DateTimeOffset dateTimeResult;
        var acceptableFormats = new string[] {
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK",
                            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                            "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.FFFK",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssK",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            "yyyyMMdd",
                            "MM/dd/yyyy",
                            "M/d/yyyy",
                            "yyyy-MM",
                            "yyyy" };
        DateTimeOffset dateTimeResult;
        var timeOffset = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact("6/1/2018 12:00:00 PM", acceptableFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTimeResult);
```

Comment: What is 12:00 AM? Isn't that 00:00 AM? I could be wrong

Comment: @JoePhillips `12:00 AM` is equivalent to `00:00` in 24 hour time. (I know, it's dumb).

Comment: @gunr2171 Well I just tested and 00:00 works fine but 12:00 doesn't so... apparently .net disagrees for some reason

Comment: @gunr2171 Oddly enough, even changing it to `hh` doesn't work with 12 hour time. It still expects 00

Comment: This works: `DateTime.TryParseExact("6/1/2018 12:00:00 AM", @"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out result);`

Comment: @RufusL SOrry for misinformation. Looks like I had a bad test case!

Comment: Thanks to @gunr2171 this works: M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you have this problem is because your format is asking for a 24-hour hour component. `12`, in 24-hour time, ALWAYS means "noon". You can't have "noon AM" because [AM is only for times between midnight and noon (exclusive)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954191).

This line throws an exception because of an invalid input format:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("6/1/2018 12:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If I change `HH` to `hh`, then it works:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("6/1/2018 12:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

// returns a valid DateTimeOffset object, which in
// my culture is displayed as '6/1/2018 12:00:00 AM -04:00'
// (I happen to be in -4 UTC)
```